# Importing CSV file to excel with special setup

Tags: excel, csv, graphics

I want to make a excel to create a graphic with my CSV file

My CSV look like that

```
date;productname;nb_sold
20211103;blabla;100
20211103;bloblo;134
20211103;toto;34
20211102;blabla;15
20211102;bloblo;145
20211102;toto;12
20211101;blabla;45
20211101;bloblo;132
20211101;toto;36
```

I'd like to import that to excel but when I do, I don't know how to create a special output

In order to do my graphic I need to have something like :

```
           blabla | bloblo | toto
20211103 | 100    | 134    | 34
20211102 | 15     | 145    | 12
20211101 | 45     | 132    | 36
```

SO one date with the product name and the number of sold for each product each day

Not sure if it's clear but I can't find how to do that :(

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Use a Pivot Table/Chart.  Dates to Rows and Product Names to columns. nb_sold to values.

Comment: I created a sample pivot table in Google Sheets; solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pivot table I created in Google Sheets, sorry, I don't have Excel. Maybe it can help get you started.

I've shared [the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R90fYjwFGqr9akBH_c1yJz2r1htcX4YBC6yIgpqVaWM/edit?usp=sharing) so you can copy it and try to modify it.

[image]